# Corpus Analysis for Salesforce?

Tags: data, parsing

I am asking this question here instead of Stack Overflow because I believe it has relevance to other Salesforce developers. If I am mistaken and this post starts racking up close votes, I will move it there instead.

I have a large dataset that I am trying to analyze. Approximately 122k emails, broken out into two types I actually care about: `Billing` with 31k and `Support` with 91k. My task is to find keywords (or combinations thereof) that predict type.

**My questions:**

What type of analysis is befitting of this task? I believe it is called `Corpus Analysis`, but I'm not really sure. Are there any in platform tools are out there for this sort of analysis?

I am currently going through and using `Python` to figure out combinations with `itertools`, counting how many emails have each combination to gauge probability. I don't really know yet if this is a reasonable approach. It's not definitely not fast.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont know any existing solutions yes. I think you can try to develop your solution by yourself. Regardless outcome, I would really like to read about your attempts and result.  IMO,  one of the approaches mab be defining basic keywords or  by yourself (probably getting combination of mostly using word pairs), and try to use Naïve Bayes Classifier and Bag-of-words_model (something similar I used ages ago in university) to build probability function based on email text and probably some extra data (maybe thats what are you doing now)

Comment: Have you investigated any of the Wave Analytics tools? I'm not familiar with them is part of why I'm asking. I can see where regEx could potentially be utilized to locate matches, but you'd first need to have a library of words you wanted to match against. Are you looking for something that analyzes content, then comes back and tells you what combinations it finds? Clarification would be helpful.

Comment: I doubt we could get the executive team to pony up for Wave, I have heard it's somewhat pricey. I am trying to build out the most predictive combinations based on the dataset we already have, so that moving forward I can attempt to categorize accurately. @crmprogdev

Comment: If that's the case, unless you're choosing the words, it would seem you'd need to first use a tool that can do word recognition, then come back & tell you what it found as the most common or highest frequency words. Remove the ones that aren't relevant & have it search for posts/records that contain combinations of them. If they don't have to be adjacent words, but just contained in the record, I'd expect you'd be able to do the latter part within your database using SOSL and the 1st part with a CSV file.

Comment: @crmprogdev I am trying to find the most predictive combinations, adjacent or no. It sounds like you have enough ideas to put together a helpful answer.

Comment: Does the analysis require functions that can be done within formula fields? I just had a similar requirement but was able to calculate my "types" based off attributes of the records and build a ranking system within the formula that I could then query directly on the record. I have a feeling your requirement is more complex, but just asking.

Comment: Probably not formulas. I'm thinking build a regex using custom settings.

Comment: It might be too little too late as you've already posted your own solution below, but have you looked at the Natural Language Toolkit? http://www.nltk.org/ It contains a lot of very useful python libraries for all kinds of things that might make your life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize what I understand you're trying to do, it sounds as though you have an existing collection of data that you want to "characterize" by searching it for words that have significance to how the records are classified. You want to use these words to automatically assign some kind of value (perhaps with a confidence level?) to future records that suggest their most likely final classification before they begin manual processing.

In trying to summarize my comments, here are a few suggestions on how I think you'll want to approach this task. First, there are words that we all know are used primarily for grammatical purposes like "a", "the", "them", etc. You may want to search for those and rule them out. That having been said, taken in context, depending on your data, there are some common ones you may not want to do this with. "it" for example may refer to "the produce", "device", etc that your records refer to and thus may be of importance. That's something you'll need to decide.

We've all used word processing tools that can tell us how many words are in our document. There are other tools that contain "vocabularies" which can also tell us how many occurrences of a particular word exists within our document. In one of it's simplest forms, a web browser can scan a document using "find" to tell us how many occurrences of a word appear in a document along with showing us where they're at.

More sophisticated tools do OCR (optical character recognition) to assemble words and even create their own word dictionaries and counts from them. Those have existed for around 20 yrs now (I remember owning Adobe Acrobat Exchange in 1998). That tells me that there will be a tool available someplace that you could use to characterize your csv file by word, word count, etc., assembling a complete dictionary containing every word in your records for you if you desired. Exactly what that tool or tools(s) is, I can't tell you off-hand.

If you need to build your own tool, you could obviously do some of this with eclipse. You could also do it using regEx to find patterns for 2letter words, 3 letter words & more for each letter of the alphabet, in the process manually compiling your own dictionary and removing words from your csv file that you believe to not have any significance or bearing on your results.

Depending on the nature of your records, you might even be able to structure queries to do what I've described above using either SOSL or SOQL (also perhaps SASL if you're part of the beta).

Once you've created your library of existing words or terms you want to work with, you'll then be able to use SOSL or SOQL to determine their significance based on the number of records returned and/or the count of occurrences where the two words appear together. You might see where obvious patterns of two or more pairs of words appear to have significance. If you do and one word is common to both, it might be worth running queries for the 3 words together. That part of the analysis will of course be what requires your interpretive skills.

I'd encourage you to plot your results of your testing and "normalize" the results to see if it fits a gaussian distribution pattern. If it does, that should increase your confidence in both the reliability and significance of the conclusions you've drawn from your testing.

Comment: Astute interpretation. I have some updates to add, but this is spot on. I ended up looking at consecutive words from 2-7 in a row. Trying to explore a few different definitions of consecutive words to improve classification rate and/or confidence level.

Comment: Unless you're interpreting data from the same user/author or people trained to input data according to your instructions, I'd expect consecutive words to be strongly influenced by location, education, and other socioeconomic background influences that could easily make that analysis of little value. A "soda" is "pop" and also a "soft drink" in different parts of the country. The same applies to a sack, bag, poke and pouch for example. To use the proper terminology, this is also a matter of dialects.

Comment: I think it will be pretty effective. A lot of these are responses from our reps, so there should be some level of consistency. For instance almost 10% of our values in the support bucket contain "case origin", but less than .5% in the billing bucket.

Answer (score 3):

I won't share the `Python` script I used here, because it is not a pretty thing. But I can describe my approach. At its essence, all I did was look for consecutive word frequency. I played around with the expressions a fair amount and ended up settling on the following:

```
expression = '.*'.join(['[\w\'@]+'] * word_count)
one word     [\w'@]+
two words    [\w'@]+.*[\w'@]+
three words  [\w'@]+.*[\w'@]+.*[\w'@]+
etc.
```

I ran up to 7 words, but only found useful data from 1-5.

From this expression, I generated a `set` of all results for each email body. Then I counted how many emails a given set element appears in for each category. This gave me a basic data structure like:

```
phrase     support    billing
from       53595      16514
message    41649      15372
your       41493      16534
this       37288      13067
```

Not super useful. But, I know that support has 91.2k records and billing has 31.2k records, so I can make this a little more valuable by adding the percentages.

```
phrase     support    billing    support %    billing %
from       53595      16514      58.77%       52.93%
message    41649      15372      45.67%       49.27%
your       41493      16534      45.50%       52.99%
this       37288      13067      40.89%       41.88%
```

From there, I can deduce the ratio of `support %/billing %` and vice versa and use this metric to estimate predictive power.

```
phrase            support %    billing %    support ratio    billing ratio
origin            9.60%        0.47%        20.52            0.05
persons           8.07%        0.70%        11.55            0.09
entities          8.01%        0.66%        12.08            0.08
retransmission    7.99%        0.58%        13.69            0.07
hesitate          0.54%        6.54%        0.08             12.16
postal            0.03%        5.28%        0.01             155.39
postallog         0.00%        5.17%        0                1000
```

I filtered on everything over 10 for both, but that ended up predicting billing quite poorly. So I increased the threshold to only use a billing ratio of at least 100.

I then used these expressions to categorize the existing data. My expression would just be an or join on all of the predictors, e.g. `(?si)(origin|persons|entities)`. The results:

```
Category    % Emails Matched    Accuracy
Support     50.3%               89.4%
Billing     7.8%                95.6%
Unmatched   41.9%               0%
```